# Is Hela, in fact, the rightful heir to Odin's throne?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, thor-ragnarok

In the movie *Thor: Ragnarok (2017)*, Hela says:

> "I am Hela, Odin's firstborn... the rightful heir to the throne."

Is she, in fact, correct?  *Is* she the rightful heir?  I recall lots of people fighting her for various reasons but I don't seem to recall anyone actually refuting her claim.

(As this does not seem to be addressed within the movies, references from the comics *et cetera* are also welcome.)

Comment: nope, see japan ... rightful heir is male ...

Comment: @Oni: the fact that Japan had male primogeniture tells us absolutely bubkis about the inheritance laws of Asgard.

Comment: She certainly *thinks* she's the rightful heir. I would imagine that trying to depose her father and murdering hordes of Asgardian Valkyrie would disqualify her from the position.

Comment: I'll see your Japan @Oni and raise you a Windsor line

Comment: When conflicts over succession arise, rightful claims don't usually matter as much as bigger army diplomacy.

Comment: Hela is not Odin's daughter in the comics, 616 at least, so you're not going to get an answer there.

Comment: @NKCampbell Not to be picky, but under the old (barely recently updated) [UK rule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUY6HGqYweQ&vl=en) she still couldn't be picked as an heir since she had a brother

Comment: A quote from George R R Martin’s _A Clash of Kings_ seems relevant here. “Oh, there was talk of the blood ties between Baratheon and Targaryen, of weddings a hundred years past, of second sons and elder daughters. No one but the maesters care about any of it. Robert won the throne with his warhammer." Hela’s legitimacy comes from victory in battle, not birth.

Answer (score 4):

At one point in time yes, however, at that point in time no. There are two main things to consider here:

Hela was imprisoned and banished by Odin, if he wanted her to still be his heir he wouldn’t have imprisoned her and removed all traces of her. She was no longer in the line of succession as is clear from *Thor* when he is shown to be the heir.

> **Odin:** Her violent appetites grew beyond my control. I couldn't stop her, so I imprisoned her. Locked her away.
>
> <sub>*Thor: Ragnarok*</sub>

> **Odin:** Gungnir. Its aim is true, its power strong. With it I have defended Asgard and the lives of the innocent across the Nine Realms since the time of the Great Beginning. And though the day has come for a new King to wield his own weapon -- that duty remains the same. Thor Odinson, my heir, my first-born. So long entrusted with this mighty hammer, Mjolnir. Forged in the heart of a dying star, from the sacred metal of Uru. Only one may lift it. Only one is worthy. Who wields this hammer commands the lightning and the storm. Its power has no equal -- as a weapon, to destroy, or as a tool, to build. It is a fit companion for a King.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

Of note in the quote from *Thor* is that Odin states Thor is his heir and also the part about Mjolnir. We know Hela used to wield Mjolnir and was for a time his second in command, she was clearly his heir and leader however it was taken away from her when she grew too violent and was imprisoned.

Also we need to look at the full quote Hela uses that you’ve supplied and it’s context.

> **Hela:** I am Hela, Odin's first born, Commander of the legions of Asgard, the rightful heir to the throne, and the Goddess of Death. My father is dead. As are the princes. You're welcome. We were once the seat of absolute power in the Cosmos. Our supremacy was unchallenged, yet Odin stopped at Nine Realms. Our destiny is to rule over all others. And I am here to restore that power. Kneel before me...and rise into the ranks of my great conquest.
>
> <sub>*Thor: Ragnarok*</sub>

Firstly, she is clearly saying things that she *was*, she clearly isn’t the Commander of the legions anymore as that is who she is talking to who are opposing her. She is trying to convince those Asgardians, its army, that she is the rightful heir and for them to join her.

The context that she is talking to Hogun and the legions and that they don’t know her and that she is trying to get them to join her says a lot. The whole point is to get them on her side or so she can fight them and get them out of the way. If she really was the heir, she a) wouldn’t have to do that and b) they would know who she was.

Comment: The underlying assumption of your answer is "the heir is whoever Odin says it is". Do we know whether this assumption is supported by Asgardian law? In many times and places in Earth's history, it was not in the current ruler's power to specify the next ruler.

Comment: @Martha there’s nothing explicit on it but considering Odin passes it on to his heir when he wants to it seems to be his word. Or his heir is his “first born” either way the evidence works in both cases and I didn’t assume Odin chooses the heir in my answer as either interpretation here work. Of course it _may_ be wrong but I don’t think we have any word on the matter.

Comment: Here I was, thinking that whatever Odin says *is* Asgardian law.